# Is there a way to extend a JPA entity to add relationships?

Tags: java, jpa

So I've got a property class

```
public class Property {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PROPERTY_ID")
    private Long propertyId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="TYPE_CODE")
    private Integer typeCode;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

That I want to use to get limited information for requests that pull ALL the properties in my database.

But I also want a class that utilizes the DB constraints to make relationships

```
public class ExportProperty extends Property {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_CODE")
    private ExportPropertyType type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ExportPropertyPhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

That I can use to get ALL data for a single property.

Is this possible? Or do I need to rethink my strategy?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Why don't you use Lazy loading? Eager is usually a bad idea anyway. That way you only need one unique class with all these columns, JPA will only load what's requested.

Comment: I don't have access to the code while it's in the transaction. I run a service with the provided query, it translates the object to a json and sends it back to me.

Comment: I think you are looking for `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` or something similar.

Comment: That definitely seems to be the right-ish track (even though it seems like that tool was really made for different _types_ of data instead of different sets of the _same_ data), but If I make two classes that map to the same table, it gives me a "duplicate mapping" error

Comment: What about `@MappedSuperclass` ?

Comment: Ah! yeap I think that'll work for what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Guillaume F. I was able to find a solution.

I have a common supertype class that includes any common fields

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class PropertySuper {
    @Id
    @Column(name="PROPERTY_ID")
    private Long propertyId;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

A class that has just the data in the Property table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROPERTY")
public class Property extends PropertySuper {

    @Column(name="TYPE_CODE")
    private Integer typeCode;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

and a class that has all of the JPA links

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROPERTY")
public class FullProperty extends PropertySuper {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_CODE")
    private FullPropertyType type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<FullPropertyPhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```